# Infinite scroll pagination ag-Grid initial page size issue

Tags: javascript, datatable, ag-grid

I'm trying to write some code that will allow me to use the `ag-Grid` library with the *infinite scrolling* method.

But I'm stuck with the parameters to correctly configure this behavior.

Let's say, for example, that I want to retrieve pages from the server of 20 items at a time. If I have understood correctly [the API](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-infinite-scrolling/) the parameter that allows me to set the size of the page is `cacheBlockSize`.

Actually, every call to the method defined in the `datasource` with the `getRows` parameter requires 20 lines at a time.

But, in the initial phase, not just one call is made, as I would expect, but more than one. Unless you set a very large `cacheBlockSize` (eg. 100 or more in the example below). And I can't understand if this behavior is configurable or not (maybe with `paginationPageSize` ??).

Eg.

with this parameters:

```
var gridOptions = {
  enableServerSideSorting: true,
  enableServerSideFilter: false,
  rowModelType: 'infinite',
  columnDefs: columnDefs,
  //paginationPageSize: 20,
  cacheBlockSize: 20,
  maxConcurrentDatasourceRequests: 1,
  infiniteInitialRowCount: 1
};
```

As you can see [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/D7pUEweuQGA4qXaIGJkm?p=preview), at the beginning instead of a single call that loads 20 lines are made 3 that load in total 20*3=60 lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you are seeing multiple requests is due to number of records displayed in the grid at a time are greater than the page size.

Let's say, you have page size of 20 (i.e. at a time 20 records are being fetched from the server) and due to the height of the grid, if grid is able to show more than 20 records, let's say 30, then it will fetch the next block from the server.

Check the live example: [ag-grid: infinite-scroll-pagination-ag-grid-initial-page-size-issue](https://plnkr.co/edit/pulpwnAAWEdWKGr9iI26?p=preview)

```
<div id="myGrid" style="height: 300px;" class="ag-theme-balham"></div>
```

Here, I have set height in such a way that the grid will display only 9 records and hence it hasn't fetched the next block from the server.

If  you increase the height gradually, you will notice more requests.

This makes sense. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, this make sense! It seems that it ask for almost twice as many as there fit on the page. tanks!

Comment: Hey @Paritosh I tried this but still my react app makes two calls even with 100 px of height. Can you help ?

Comment: @Paritosh never mind. I have observed that as long as cacheBlockSize is 20 or higher and if we adjust the height accordingly, it doesn't make unwanted indirect request for next block. So even with the plunker you have shared, I changed the cacheBlockSize from 20 to 19 and kept the height same i.e. 300px, it made another request.